# How to represent a triangle of integers?

Tags: java, python, algorithm, integer, int

This addresses "a specific programming problem" from [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

I am working on an interview question from [Amazon Software Interview](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Given-a-triangle-of-integers-find-the-path-of-the-largest-sum-without-skipping-QTN_623875.htm)
The question is " Given a triangle of integers, find the path of the largest   sum without skipping. "

My question is how would you represent a triangle of integers?

I looked this up on [Triangle of Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143410/how-to-print-a-triangle-of-integers-with-number-of-lines-specified-by-the-user)  and saw that a triangle of integers looked something like

```
1
2      3
4      5      6
7      8      9      10
11     12     13     14     15
```

What is the best way(data structure) to represent something like this? My idea was having something like

```
int[] r1 = {1};
int[] r2 = {2, 3};
int[] r3 = {4, 5, 6};
int[] r4 = {7, 8, 9, 10};
int[] r5 = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
```

Is this the best way to represent this triangle integer structure? I thought about using a 2 dimensional matrix structure but those have to have arrays of the same size.

Comment: well you can use a `List<Integer[]>`

Comment: If you want to get fancy and stupid at the same time, you could use a leaning tree.

Comment: java or python or both?

Comment: @Jon I don't even want to know what a leaning tree is haha

Comment: unless there are negatives, largest sum path is clearly traversing each row, summing all the integers in the triangle...:)

Comment: @גלעדברקן There's probably negatives, making it the largest sub-sequence problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put them in linear memory and access them as:

```
int triangular(int row){
 return row * (row + 1) / 2 + 1;
}

int[] r = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
for(int i=0; i<n_rows; i++){
 for(int j=0; j<=i; j++){
  System.out.print(r[triangular(i)+j]+" ");
 }System.out.println("");
}

row, column
if row>column:
 index=triangular(row)+column
```

Since it's a predictable structure there's an expression for the offset of the beginning of each row. This will be the most efficient way.

Comment: So linear memory meaning array?

Comment: Updated for a full example.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought about using a 2 dimensional matrix structure but those have to have arrays of the same size.

Not correct.

In Java you can use arrays to represent non-rectangular data structures; e.g.

```
int[][] triangle = {{1}, 
                    {2, 3},
                    {4, 5, 6},
                    {7, 8, 9, 10},
                    {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}};
```

It is an option, though not necessarily the most convenient option.

Comment: What would be more convenient?

Comment: Possibly one of the other solutions proposed by the other answers.  You can make up your own mind.

Comment: I cannot give you a specific answer on that because I have not considered the implications for the algorithms, and their ease of implementation.  However, I'm pretty sure that any of the alternatives will be easier to deal with than N different named 1-D arrays ... as in your sample code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a 2D array with guard-bands. In the example below, the 0's represent invalid entries in the array. The top and bottom rows, as well as the leftmost and rightmost columns are the guard-bands.  The advantage is that your pathfinding algorithm can wander around the array without having to constantly check for out-of-bounds array indices.

```
int[][] array =
{
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 7, 8, 9,10, 0, 0 },
    { 0,11,12,13,14,15, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

Comment: but woudn't all those 0s take up too much space?

Comment: How big is the biggest triangle?

Comment: Question doesn't say. So no stated limit, I guess

Comment: @committedandroider Well, if you go beyond 10,000 rows, then maybe the extra space taken up by the 0s matters, otherwise no.

Comment: What I was thinking about was just using one array and using some formula like what duskwuff suggested to identify the different rows of the triangle. That way you save space?

Comment: @committedandroider Right, you would save space, but is that important? With algorithms you need to consider the space complexity and the time complexity. My intuition is that time complexity will be the limiting factor with this problem, so using more space to reduce the time is a good trade-off.

Comment: But if you have one array with that formula, why would you need the extra space?

Comment: @committedandroider I think you need to go through the process of writing all the code before I can explain that to you.

Comment: This method increases both space and time complexity. It's a wasteful approach.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to represent it at all! The starting number of row `r` (starting at 0) is given by the expression:

```
r * (r + 1) / 2 + 1
```

Comment: So you represent this with one array?

Comment: If your array is literally just these numbers, you don't need an array at all. You can just calculate what the number at a given position will be without storing it anywhere.

Comment: @duskwuff his array is not just those numbers.

Comment: @duskwuff that array was just an example from another thread. I suppose the array for this problem can take any value in